# background-image with repeat-y doesnt cover the full height

Tags: css, background-image

I have the following HTML: A sidebar with a color full height an left side outside of the page of a color, so i have an image to cover the left side of the page and goes to the full height, but in chrome it doesnt cover the full height of the page with repeat-y;

my css: (doesnt work in chrome)

```
body {
    background: #000 url(../images/bar_bg.jpg) repeat-y;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I want to achieve this: 
[image]

Is there is another way to do it without images or with CSS3 maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Your html and body are not covering the entire viewport, use...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to do some work with the code, but this sounds like the margin-height needs to be set to zero.

Comment: fix it with min-height:100%; height:auto;

Answer (score 0):

solved with

```
html, body{
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
}
```